# How would I find the angular accelertion of a disk rolling up a ramp?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, torque

I need to find the angular acceleration of a hollow ball rolling (without slipping) on a ramp, given the angle of the ramp theta, the mass and radius of the ball, and gravity and other physical constants, but not frictional constants. The catch is, torque is applied to the ball that, if it were unopposed by gravity, would roll it up the hill, as below.

[image]

I don't know how to deal with the extra torque, and I'm not given information about the direction the ball will roll. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the disc rolling without slipping?

Comment: @AdityaGarg Yes, I'll specify that in an edit

Comment: What are your thoughts on this so far? Have you drawn a free body diagram showing the forces acting on the ball?

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yes, my diagram includes frictional force, normal force, gravitational force, and the torque being applied.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I also have the idea that there is a torque created by gravity and friction which opposes the applied torque, but I don't know how to deal with that numerically.

Comment: One simplifying trick is to consider rotation about a carefully selected point so as to eliminate torque from troublesome forces like friction and the normal force.

Comment: The torque is not a force.  If you are talking about the tangential force at the top of the ball, then that is correct to include.  Let's see your force balance equations in the directions parallel and perpendicular to the ramp.  Let's also see your moment balance about the center of mass of the ball.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yes, I meant the tangential force. My bad.